# Displaying a dataframe in PyQt textbrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtextbrowser

Not able to get this table aligned , it looks very messy.

```
self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.centralwidget)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 10, 500,800))
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
    self.textBrowser.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
    self.textBrowser.showMaximized()
    self.textBrowser.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Monospace"))
    self.textBrowser.setWordWrapMode(QtGui.QTextOption.NoWrap)
    self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet('color: blue')
```

[image]

Comment: could you include how you are actually putting the data frame into the text browser? also is there any reason you aren't using a  QTableView and instead using a text component?

Comment: I've not really explored PyQt a lot and wasn't aware of a QTableView. Anyway, Thanks  @chris , I will check that out and also it would be great if you could suggest any documentation (Other than the official one ) related to PyQt which I could refer while doing my project. Thanks again !

Comment: Also @chris , for your former question, this is how I'm putting the dataframe in the textbrowser ..   'self.textBrowser.setText(df_new.to_string(col_space =5,justify = "justify"))'

Answer (score 0):

A text widget is not the best way to display data that should be formatted as a table, for which QTableView (or QTableWidget) are more suitable widgets.

If you still want to use a text based widget, you have to set the font to the widget's [*text document*](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#document-prop).

```
    font = QtGui.QFont('Fonospace')
    self.textBrowser.document().setDefaultFont(font)
```